# Is there any alternate way to avoid deprecation in Apache POI, for HSSF built-in colors?

Tags: java, apache-poi, deprecated, poi-hssf, hssfworkbook

In my code i want to change the cell colors of a particular column of a HSSFWorkbook, if the text is "PASS". But when i was writing the code, lots of methods and constants like **BRIGHT_GREEN.index**, **setFillPattern**, **SOLID_FOREGROUND** are deprecated. I have searched for an  alternative in Apache POI official website, but the code given there is also deprecated. I know there is no problem if i mention @deprecation tag, but sometimes after 100-150 lines(rows), cell-color is not changing. Can anyone please tell me is there any alternative to avoid @deprecation? FYI: i am using ***poi-bin-3.17-beta1-20170701*** jars.
Thanks in advance :)

```
if(cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Pass")){
                    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BRIGHT_GREEN.index);
                    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From their documentation:

```
/**
 * @deprecated use {@link HSSFColorPredefined} instead
 */
@Deprecated
@Removal(version="3.18")
public static class BRIGHT_GREEN extends HSSFColorRef {
    private static final HSSFColorPredefined ref = HSSFColorPredefined.BRIGHT_GREEN;
    public static final short index = ref.getIndex();
    public static final int index2 = ref.getIndex2();
    public static final short[] triplet = ref.getTriplet();
    public static final String hexString = ref.getHexString();
    public BRIGHT_GREEN() { super(ref); }
}
```

So in your case: `HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BRIGHT_GREEN`

For your `setFillPattern`:

```
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Your new code should look like this

```
    style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BRIGHT_GREEN.getIndex())
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Comment: Thanks @sfat,  But now i'm facing another problem. As u said,  i have changed my code from **style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BRIGHT_GREEN.index);**  to **style.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BRIGHT_GREEN);** but i'm getting an error says: *The method setFillBackgroundColor(short) in the type HSSFCellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined), change it to setFillForeGroundColor(...) *  I tried to use **setFillForeGroundColor(..)** but again it is saying the same error and suggesting me to change it to **setFillBackGroundColor(..)**.

Comment: @BongCule updated the answer. Check the latest bit. In your case, your problem is because you are not calling `getIndex()`. A quick search on google will help you with these problems in the future :)